# How to check marker lies in multiple polygons in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-maps, maps

This code only take one polygon i want something that can take multiple polygons to check if lat lng lies in one of them or not! Any solution?

```
componentDidMount() {
  const polygon = [
    { lat: 3.1336599385978805, lng: 101.31866455078125 },
    { lat: 3.3091633559540123, lng: 101.66198730468757 },
    { lat: 3.091150714460597,  lng: 101.92977905273438 },
    { lat: 3.1336599385978805, lng: 101.31866455078125 } // last point has to be same as first point
  ];

  let point = {
    lat: 2.951269758090068,
    lng: 101.964111328125
  };

  GeoFencing.containsLocation(point, polygon)
    .then(() => console.log('point is within polygon'))
    .catch(() => console.log('point is NOT within polygon'))
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: you can call containsLocation function for each polygon in array and use something like [promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or [promise.any (still in stage 4)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). This will give you the desired output.